# How to make YOLOV7 use higher resolution for training?

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, yolo

The current requirements are as follows:

1.The input image is a picture taken by 1440x1080 camera

2.There are only two detection targets, which are approximately 40x40 pixels and 16x16 pixel balls on the picture

It seems that when yolov7 is training, the “image_size” parameter just tells it the size of the original image, and the model will still scaled image to 480x480 (complete with gray pixels if the pixel is not enough) and then go to training,My target is already small enough that zooming again makes it indistinguishable.

Is there any way to make the model to train at the native resolution of 1440x1080 (or 1440x1088 when completed as a multiple of 32)?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to divide your large image into several small images and then run the object detection module on top of that.

Comment: Agree with Robin here. Unless you retrain the model, this would be the only realistically way of doing it. And if you're retraining the model you will either (a) need to have sufficient data to get good generalization or (b) resize the training dataset (e.g. COCO) to be of the resolution you desire.